# SqlFunctions vs DbFunctions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

[SqlFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487052(v=vs.110).aspx) states that it should be used only in LINQ to Entities. [DbFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.adddays(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddDays(System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTime%7D,System.Nullable%7BSystem.Int32%7D)) also. But when I try SqlFunctions it says that, for example, `DateDiff` cannot be translated!

Why? What is the difference (besides methods signatures) between them? Are they tied to a specific version?

**Edit1**
If you replace `DbFunctions` for `SqlFunction` the resulting query wont translate and throw a exception

```
case "<>":
    return a => a.id_indice == indice.id && indice.tipoDado == (int)enumTipo.Data && DbFunctions.DiffDays(a.valorDateTime, data) == 0;
case ">":
    return a => a.id_indice == indice.id && indice.tipoDado == (int)enumTipo.Data && DbFunctions.DiffDays(a.valorDateTime, data) > 0;
case "<":
    return a => a.id_indice == indice.id && indice.tipoDado == (int)enumTipo.Data && DbFunctions.DiffDays(a.valorDateTime, data) < 0;
case ">=":
    return a => a.id_indice == indice.id && indice.tipoDado == (int)enumTipo.Data && DbFunctions.DiffDays(a.valorDateTime, data) >= 0;
case "<=":
    return a => a.id_indice == indice.id && indice.tipoDado == (int)enumTipo.Data && DbFunctions.DiffDays(a.valorDateTime, data) <= 0;
```

Comment: Just a guess: `SqlFunctions` is for LINQ-to-SQL, while `DbFunctions` is for Entity Framework.

Comment: I believe your question is answered here.  Just keep in mind, EntityFunctions is now DbFunctions as of EF6.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637317/what-is-the-difference-between-sqlfunctions-and-entityfunctions

Comment: DateDiff is expecting 3 parameters, I updated my answer.

Comment: What are you actually asking? If it's about the exception you should show the code and the exception.